# How to add species arrows/vectors to an ordination plot

Tags: r, phyloseq

I have made ordination plots of microbiome data using the R `phyloseq` functions ordinate and `plot_ordination` with a `phyloseq` object and a previously calculated distance matrix (unweighted UniFrac distances) as inputs. I would like to add some arrows that indicate which species relative abundances mainly drive the distance between the samples along the axes.

Adding scores using the function scores or `specscores.dbrda` has not worked. Is there another way to add these arrows/vectors?

Here's the code I used:

```
MDS <- ordinate(physeqobject, "MDS", distance=unifracmatrix)
plot <- plot_ordination(physeqobject, MDS, color = "variable1")

speciesscores <- scores(MDS, display = "species")
```

The first part works fine, the scores function returns this error:

```
Error in scores.default(MDS, display = "species") : 
  cannot find scores
```

I also tried it without a separate distance matrix with the (default) Bray-Curtis distances calculated within ordinate, but I still get the same error:

MDS <- ordinate(physeqobject, "MDS")